# Issue removing columns from admin table

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, wp-list-table

I'm trying to remove the columns thumbnail and featured from an admin table. At the same time I'm adding one additional column. The post type is `property`. I would like to do it via code instead of using plugin as I would need to do some additional customisations.

None of the hooks I tried seem to work.

- manage_property_posts_columns
- manage_posts_columns
- manage_property_posts_custom_column

Interesting thing is that the same code works on different post types.

What could be the issue?

```
add_filter( 'manage_property_posts_columns', 'remove_property_columns' );

function remove_property_columns( $columns ) {
    unset($columns['thumbnail']);
    unset($columns['featured']);
    $columns['test'] =  'Test' ;
    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: If the same code works on other post types, are you absolutely certain the post type you're targeting is "property"?

Comment: Yes and I have double-checked it with 
`get_post_type( get_the_ID() )`

Comment: in `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php` look the value used on line 685 if you have WordPress 5.3.1.

Comment: line 685 of `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php` is 
`return apply_filters( "manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns", $posts_columns );`
so I believe the hook is correct